# How make a preprocessor string that work with both narrow and wide

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

I have to make two projects with different names. Both projects will share the same code.

So I started replacing the places that call the old name to a preprocessor in stdafx.h called APP_NAME

In stdafx.h I put

```
#define APP_NAME _T("My name")
```

And when I find code like

```
function(parm1,_T("My old name have a error"));
```

I want to replace with

```
function(parm1, APP_NAME _T(" have a error"));
```

But, a lot of errors appear when mixing wide ( T("x") or L"") with pure narrow ("")

> error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

Is it possible to do any preprocessor magic to overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is that you define a macro APP_NAME but then use NAME later. If that is not the real problem, then you simply need to consistently use _T("...") so that all strings will be prefixed correctly (and assuming _T expands to nothing more than a wide or narrow qualified string in your environment).

Answer (score 2):

Move the `_T` to where the macro is used, because that's where the correct encoding is known.

```
#define APP_NAME "My name"
function(parm1, _T(APP_NAME) _T(" have a error"));
```

---

But you shouldn't actually have to, this is a bug in Visual C++ 2010.  C++0x requires that (section `[lex.string]`):

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated.  If both string literals have the same *encoding-prefix*, the resulting concatenated string literal has that *encoding-prefix*.  **If one string literal has no *encoding-prefix*, it is treated as a string literal of the same *encoding-prefix* as the other operand**.  If a UTF-8 string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal token, the program is ill-formed.  Any other concatenations are conditionally supported with implementation-deﬁned behavior.  [ *Note*:  This concatena- tion is an interpretation, not a conversion. Because the interpretation happens in translation phase 6 (after each character from a literal has been translated into a value from the appropriate character set), a string literal’s initial rawness has no eﬀect on the interpretation or well-formedness of the concatenation.  — *end note* ]

Answer (score 0):

Have a `APP_NAME` and a `APP_NAME_W`, one narrow and one wide. Use whichever one is appropriate in that context.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix narrow and wide strings.  However, if you consistently use _T() then everything will work.  Make sure both projects and all compilation units have the same setting for UNICODE which controls whether _T() will be "" or L"".